# Running a function in each iteration of a loop as a new process in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=4)

def createResults(uniqPath):
    *(there is some code here that populates a list - among other things)*

for uniqPath in uniqPaths:
    pool.map(createResults, uniqPath)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I don't know if it's possible, but can I run the createResults function that gets called in that loop as a new process for each iteration?

I'm populating a list using a 4 million line file and it's taking 24+ hours to run. (Obviously the code above does not work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for uniqPath in uniqPaths:
    pool.map(createResults, uniqPath)
```

Do this:

```
pool.map(createResults, uniqPaths)
```

You must use map on the iterable itself in order to run in a concurrent fashion.
Keep in mind though - Populating a list means the list won't be shared between the processes, and if it does using [`Array()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), make sure it's process-safe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Bharel. What do you mean when you say "You must use map on the iterable itself in order to run in a concurrent fashion" ?
That's exactly what I would like to try. Thanks again

Comment: @Shaun Given an iterable (in this case `uniqPaths`), you should use `pool.map()` on it in order for the pool to run all of it's values at the same time. Else, every time you iterate in the `for` loop, you wait for the map to finish before continuing to the next one.